# Can the following property of unitary matrices be generalised to unitary operators on the Hilbert space L2(R^N)?

Tags: functional-analysis

I was looking for some information on functional analysis and found out that [any unitary matrix can be represented as the exponential of (a Hermitian matrix multiplied by the imaginary unit).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix)
After reading it, I wondered whether the same property carries over to unitary operators on L2(R^N) as well or not. In more formal terms, I want to know if the following is true: for any unitary operator A: L2(R^N) -> L2(R^N), there exists a densely defined (possibly unbounded) self-adjoint operator B such that A=exp(i*B) as operators on at least one dense Banach subspace (call it V) of L2(R^N), the operator exponential being defined by the corresponding Taylor series, converging in some Banach seminorm that is bounded by a constant multiple of the L2(R^N) norm with respect to the space V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the kind of problem the spectral theorem is made for.

Let $U$ be a unitary operator. By the spectral theorem, $U$ is unitarily equivalent (via a unitary $V$) to a multiplication operator $M_\phi$, and the function $\phi$ can be taken to have values in $\mathbb{T}=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: \lvert z\rvert=1\}$. For $z\in \mathbb{T}$ let $f(z)$ be the unique number from $[0,2\pi)$ such that $e^{i f(z)}=z$. The map $f$ is of course not continuous, but it is certainly measurable, and that is all we need.

Then $f(U)$, defined as $V^\ast M_{f\circ \phi}V$, is a bounded self-adjoint operator, and the equation $e^{if(z)}=z$ implies $e^{if(U)}=U$. Since $f(U)$ is bounded, the operator exponential can be computed using the exponential series, i.e.,
$$
e^{if(U)}\xi=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{i^k}{k!}f(U)^k \xi.
$$

Comment: I had already known the spectral theorem, but I didn't realise that a solution this simple was possible. Thank you for the answer!